# Import Amazon S3 files into database

Tags: javascript, database, amazon-s3, media-player

My client bought around 60GB Amazon S3 storage to upload music. Now I have to build an application that has a JavaScript music player. Is it possible to import the music files into a MySQL database for example, and then make the player read those files? I guess it's possible to read the files directly from the Amazon S3 storage in my JavaScript player, but every user has a customized playlist etc, so I believe that a database is necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import music file to local database.
you can create a user playlist database and associate s3 file path to it.

Like:
**UserPlayList Table**

```
UserID int
S3FilePath varchar
```

Comment: Does it work the same way for the JavaScript music player? I mean, I should just pass the full S3 file path and it reads it?